# Creating multiple themes in a single ionic 2 app

Tags: sass, ionic2

We are currently migrating a hybrid application from a selfmade framework to ionic 2. In the old app we had multiple sass files that compiled into a singe css file containing different themes that were applied to the app by switching a class on the body (like ".skin-red").

Is there a way to achieve that with the $varaiables map of ionic or will i have to create multiple style files with a custom written task and change the used css file at runtime with js code? (which i'd rather not do)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow this  [User-Selected Style Themes in an Ionic 2 Application](https://webcake.co/theming-an-ionic-2-application/) tutorial.

Or you can set all colors using ts variable and update color hash code run time.

**HTML:**

```
 <ion-header>
        <ion-toolbar color="primary" [style.background]="headerBackground"> 
            <ion-title> 
            </ion-title>
        </ion-toolbar>
 </ion-header>
```

**TS:**

```
public headerBackground = '#ddd';
```

Should be shared variable.